# Sending an image via POST Multipart (HTTPRequest)

Tags: c#, httprequest, http-post

I'm trying to send an image to a server, using HTTP Post Multipart. Everything else is fine, I have all the boundrys set and stuff.

But what do I have to do to the image before hand? Do I have to convert it to binary? Here is the header data from the header (using Fiddler). This is what I need to upload:

```
-----------------------------7daea2aa40c80
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pict"; filename="pic.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/pjpeg

<Binary here ... or at least I think it is> ..
�����JFIF���������C� (lots more of this I removed)
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the File.ReadAllBytes function to read the file into a byte[]. From there you can use a StreamWriter to output the bytes into your reponse. There is no conversion needed.

Comment: Awesome stuff! Spent hours on the hunt for info related to this!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you want to use a Content-Transfering-Encoding set to base64. Then you simply does File.ReadAllBytes if your file into a byte array, for then to use the [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) method to converting to base64.

You can read more about it at Wikipedia's article about [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding)

Example

```
string data =
       @"----------------------------7daea2aa40c80\n";
       + @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pict"; filename="{0}"\n"
       + @"Content-Type: image/pjpeg\n";
       + @"\n{1}";

string filename = "pict.jpg";
string bytes = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
string request = string.Format(data, filename, bytes);
```